# Вертикальная прокрутка в Edge вне блока, в остальных браузерах - внутри. Как унифицировать?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Прошу посмотреть на код ниже. Мне необходимо, чтобы .child был по умолчанию по ширине .parent, не меньше (но со скролом внутри родителя), а при увеличении ширины у .child ширина его .parent не менялась. Как реализовать? История с float: left для .child не подходит, потому что при увеличении ширины .child, ширина .parent меняться не должна. А ширина самого .parent в свою очередь тоже не фиксирована, а подстраивается под ширину .caption. Разумеется, о кастомизации скролла с помощью js и прочего речи не идет - интересует чистый css. Код:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 29px !important;
  background: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #dcdcdc);
  padding: 0;
  border: #a6a6a6 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.6);
  color: #000000;
  font: 12px verdana, sans;
}

.child {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="caption">Тест тест тест</div>
  <div class="child">1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br></div>

</div>
```

Что получилось. Справа Edge, слева - все остальные. Вопрос - как же все таки загнать скролл у Edge "в берега"? Спасибо!

[image: Справа Edge - слева все остальные браузеры]

Comment: Попробуйте с box-sizing поиграться

Comment: Обыгрался уже )) Передохнул и  с новыми силами начал

Answer (score 1):

```css
.child {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  **width: 100%;**
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 0px
}
```

Установить значение "width" а не "min-width"